# Client server ios Application

Tags: iphone, ios, client-server

Whats the best way to do an application where an phone is the server and the others phones are the clients. The clients will do requests to the server and the server will respond..Requests maybe to the server sends the real time audio that they are capturing..Whats the best way to do this in ios? Using UDP Multicast? Or an TCP Socket per client?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11620017/352891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UDP multicast will cast your messages to *all* devices in your network (hence the name). It also does not guarantee delivery and it does not garauntee delivery order (FOFI) either. In most situations, UDP isn't really a good idea.

TCP is a really great alternative, it's easy to use, and it does garuantee all those things and there are many frameworks or C libraries out there that can help you a lot.

Personally, I'ld recommend using `libuv` and attaching the `uv` runloop to `NSRunloop`, but you can use `AsyncSocket` too, if you'ld rather like to stick to Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i have the idea that sending audio over TCP isn't a good idea. Its true and i have to use UDP right? Regards

Comment: I think TCP is excellent for that purpose, since it guarantees the delivery order (which obviously is very important for audio) and only sends the audio file to the peer that requested it (no multicast). Don't forget that all websites (e.g. Youtube) and Spotify also use TCP to transport audio (even though that's different from an iOS-to-iOS architecture).

Comment: thank you for your help..You have any idea for the besting way to turn on the microphone of server iphone  and sends its capture audio for the others iphone clients?